# Is it possible to let a user input any number of words one per line using the input function?

Tags: python, input

I was wondering is it possible to let a user enter any number of words one per line using the input function. So for example, let's say I have the following prompt:

Enter any number of words, one per line, or a blank line to stop:

and the output is something like this:

```
hello
my
name
is
dave
```

What would the code for this look like?

Comment: yes, that's totally possible, it will require a bit more code though than just calling the input function

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you try writing code that calls `input` *more than once*? For example, using a loop? I mean, `input` reads one line of input; you want to read multiple lines of input, which is the same thing as reading one line of input, multiple times. Right? So....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply :

```
while True:
    x = input()
    if x == '':
        break
```